# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) : Drop Down Menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, sigabrt

So I have recently encountered a Sigabrt crash that our team was unable to solve. It involves a segue crash. When I press the school rules button from the Information View Controller, it pushes (performs segue) to the School Rules View Controller. However, when I press the back button (on the navigation bar on top), it goes back to the Information View Controller, but then crashes. Here below are my crash logs and View Controllers:

Note: I have checked for all normal Sigabrt crashes, including linked outlets, Segue Identifier, etc.

```
Application did finish launching
2018-04-29 11:13:47.156002+0800 DBS[6288:361798] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 100
DidDisappear ()
true
(8.0, 8.0, 375.0, 812.0)
(8.0, 145.111111111111, 359.0, 521.777777777778)
2018-04-29 11:14:19.188187+0800 DBS[6288:361798] [general] Caught exception during autorelease pool drain NSGenericException: Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000669700 "DBS.dropDownView:0x7fcda1537890.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x60000066a300 "DBS.dropDownBtn:0x7fcda1538510'▼ Introduction'.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal. userInfo: (null)
2018-04-29 11:14:19.203034+0800 DBS[6288:361798] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000669700 "DBS.dropDownView:0x7fcda1537890.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x60000066a300 "DBS.dropDownBtn:0x7fcda1538510'▼ Introduction'.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010adbe1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a00c031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ae33975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   DBS                                 0x0000000107f64206 _T03DBS11dropDownBtnC18didMoveToSuperviewyyF + 566
    4   DBS                                 0x0000000107f644b4 _T03DBS11dropDownBtnC18didMoveToSuperviewyyFTo + 36
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010c5f7400 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 899
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010c5f6fea -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 808
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010c5f4e9e __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 169
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010c5f4990 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 479
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010c5ddc67 -[UIView dealloc] + 508
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a0211b2 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_119AutoreleasePoolPage3popEPv + 860
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad08136 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 22
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad44eae __CFRunLoopRun + 2350
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ad4430b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011396ca73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010c53f0b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
    16  DBS                                 0x0000000107f68507 main + 55
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f37d955 start + 1
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here below is my DropDownButton View Controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol dropDownProtocol {
    func dropDownPressed(string : String)
}

class dropDownBtn: UIButton, dropDownProtocol {

    func dropDownPressed(string: String) {
        self.setTitle("▼ \(string)", for: .normal)
        self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.dismissDropDown()
    }

    var dropView = dropDownView()

    var height = NSLayoutConstraint()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        dropView = dropDownView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 8, y: 100, width: 0, height: 0))
        dropView.delegate = self
        dropView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
        self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: dropView)
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }

    var isOpen = false
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if isOpen == false {

            isOpen = true

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])

            //            if self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height > 400 {
            //                self.height.constant = 400
            //            } else {
            //                self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height
            //            }
            self.height.constant = self.dropView.tableView.contentSize.height+8

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
                self.dropView.center.y += self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            }, completion: nil)

        } else {
            isOpen = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
            self.height.constant = 0
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
                self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    func dismissDropDown() {
        isOpen = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height])
        self.height.constant = 0
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height])
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.dropView.center.y -= self.dropView.frame.height / 2
            self.dropView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the error. It's about a constraint problem. Most of the code you posted has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable+to+activate+constraint+with+anchors+because+they+have+no+common+ancestor) on the error.

Comment: Yeah, I was suspecting that. But will a constraint problem cause a segue crash? I would like to know.

Comment: You don't have a segue crash. You have a constraint issue crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `didMoveToSuperview` function assumes it is only called when the view is added to its superview. But it is also called when it is removed from its superview. If you look at the stack trace you can see the crash is happening when the view is being removed. You need to update your `didMoveToSuperview` so it only runs the code when being added and not when being removed.

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    if let superview = self.superview {
        superview.addSubview(dropView)
        superview.bringSubview(toFront: dropView)
        dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
    }
}
```